# Reducing a javascript object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[{duration: 12, place: 3}, {duration: 21, place: 4}, {duration: 22, place: 3}]
```

I want to combine all the durations from the same place value.
How do I write a function in javascript that can give me an output like this?

```
[{duration: 34, place: 3}, {duration: 21, place: 4}]
```

Comment: All 3 items have different value of place. Can you explain on the merging logic?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal sorry typo. Fixed!

Comment: what effort have you made to solving the problem?

Comment: Backing up @Daniel A. White, you will get much better responses when you demonstrate that you have attempted a solution, or show that you do understand some concepts of the problem.  That way people feel like they are just giving you a helping hand, not doing all the work and preventing you from learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` to group the objects with same place value.

```js
const array = [{duration: 12, place: 3}, {duration: 21, place: 4}, {duration: 22, place: 3}],
      result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, {duration, place}) => {
        (a[place] || (a[place] = {duration: 0, place})).duration += duration;
        return a;
      }, {}));
      
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```